# Choice of capacitor for high frequency application

Tags: power, capacitor, wireless, induction, resonance

I want to recreate [this wireless power transfer system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3E5PUnYlaTM&t=3s) that utilizes two resonating LC circuits and induction for power transfer. I want to know the best type of capacitor to use in the LC resonator circuit. Should it be ceramic or film or something else? The frequency of operation is 150 kHz.

Comment: 150 kHz is [low frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_frequency).

Comment: *the best type* Then you will have to define what is "best" first. Suppose the caps with the most ideal behavior cost $ 100 a piece, is that what you need? Or will a 10 cents cap be good enough? In practice at 150 kHz nearly all standard ceramic caps will still be good. Only above 1 MHz you need to pay more attention. How? By looking at the **datasheet**.

Comment: Thank you. Your writing style is a bit aggressive but its okay.

Answer (score 4):

Ceramic C0G has my vote.  Stable, works well into the RF region.

Comment: Only good up to about 100nF though, I've not watched the video so don't know what the OP needs. I agree though, C0G is about as good as it gets.

Answer (score 3):

The inductor is the weak spot as in most tuned circuits. This is further weakened by the ferrite plate losses and the MOSFET drivers are the third weakest spot. So choosing a capacitor to run at 150 kHz isn't that big of a deal and I can see that the guy in the video used a polyester type initially then went to a C0G type later on. I'd prefer a C0G because it won't get as warm and is more stable with temperature variations.

Choose a capacitor voltage rating that is at least 10 times the DC supply voltage to the H bridge because (like with any LC series tuned circuit) you will get significant AC voltage amplification.

Answer (score 3):

The cap sees high resonant voltage and sees 150KHz as Andy aka has stated.The currents in the car lamp incandescant demo part of the U tube video would be Amperes .The   little thru hole ceramic cap that was shown on the demo would not do this 24/7.The cap must be rated for the high frequency current ,this is why paralleled caps are common .I use my old school polyprop bulky caps that have never let me down when it comes to lab demos .